# Why does my div have so much empty space on the left when I have floated it to the left?

Tags: css

I am [trying the `shape-outside` property](https://github.com/Sathyaish/Practice/blob/master/CSS/shape-outside.html) and it doesn't work on Firefox 60.0.1 yet, which is fine because it is probably not yet supported on that browser, and it does work kind of alright on Chrome v66 again because of the presence of browser support.

But my question is: why is there a margin or empty space on the left of my `div#inner` when I have specified `float:left` and there is nothing before it that floats to the left?

Here is how my page looks on both the browsers Firefox and Chrome and then following that is the code.

**On Firefox v60.0.1**

[image]

**On Chrome v66**

[image]

```css
div#outer {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

div#inner {
  float: left;
  
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 10em;
  border: 12px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  
  background-color: cyan;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  
  clip-path: circle(50%);
  
  shape-outside:  circle(50%);
  -webkit-shape-outside:  circle(50%);
}
```

```html
<div id = "outer">
  <span>Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world!</span>
  <div id = "inner">Foo bar</div>
<span>Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world! Hello, world! Hello world!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `clip-path` to see – that’s the size of element that was considered for that part of the layout.

Comment: @Ry- I actually grew this organically and it did not have `clip-path`, and then I put it in, so I know that that has nothing to do with the problem, because if it had, it would affect the right side, too, which it isn't affecting.

Comment: Are you asking why the text doesn’t also appear to the left, then? I took the question as being about why the element is positioned where it is.

Comment: @Ry: No, I am not asking why the text doesn't also appear on the left. I am asking *why there is empty space on the left of the div#inner* when there isn't supposed to be, according to my understanding, since I have floated the element entirely to the left.

Comment: Okay. I answered that, then. Maybe rephrasing will help: clipping doesn’t affect layout, and `shape-outside` only affects how text wraps around an element; it doesn’t affect the layout of the element itself.

Comment: It appears that in FF clip-path does not have any effect on the actual size of the element, only on its visual size.

Comment: @connexo Bang on you are!

Comment: @Ry- Check the Chrome screenshot - clipping does definitely affect the layout of the surrounding text.

Comment: @connexo: No, that’s the `shape-outside`.

Comment: Quoting [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path): "CSS clip-path property (for HTML) - CR

Method of defining the visible region of an HTML element using SVG or a shape definition."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer with a bit of tinkering. @connexo is right in the comments section to this question.

Basically, I removed the `clip-path` and the thing clicked.

[image]

Here are a few observations that clear up a few misconceptions I had:

1. `clip-path` and `shape-outside` are not dependent on each other. More specifically, `shape-outside` does not rely on the presence of `clip-path`.
2. `clip-path` does not change the size of the element. It only makes it *appear* that much smaller.

   So, the part of the element has been clipped *does still exist on both the left and the right sides*. Just that because I have `shape-outside` enabling inline content to wrap around the right side of my `div`, it appears that the right side was clipped but the left wasn't. In reality, neither of the sides were really clipped. They were simply redrawn so as to make the visual appearance smaller.

Comment: Check [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside) - support for css shapes is behind a flag in FF. It's a feature [in development](https://platform-status.mozilla.org/#css-shapes).

Comment: That's right. Actually, even in Chrome, I saw that `shape-outside` still doesn't work. Only the vendor extension `-webkit-shape-outside` does.